# yamlfix not using configuration + (neo)vim usage

Tags: command-line, vim, vi, yaml, nvim

I'm using yamlfix with [ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) in vim.
I followed [these steps](https://lyz-code.github.io/yamlfix/) because I wanted to remove the automatic "---" adding on top of the file every time I save my work (and some others default configurations).

For some reason, the file is correctly fixed, but my configuration is skipped..

So I decided to try with CLI in order to test my config.

yamlfix exits without error, fixes my file, but is completely skipping my configuration..

The configuration is in ~/pyproject.toml:

```
# pyproject.toml
[tool.yamlfix]
explicit_start = false
```

The command is

```bash
yamlfix -c ~/pyproject.toml file.yaml
```

Do I miss something ? Do I need something more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `yamlfix` directly from the command line (or via a shell spawned from Vim, and not [via e.g. `maison`](https://lyz-code.github.io/yamlfix/#auto-configure-through-pyprojecttoml)), your TOML configuration file should contain no section headers:

```bash
$ cat myconfig.toml
explicit_start = false
```

You may then run `yamlfix` from the command line like so:

```bash
$ cat test.yml
---
test: some test data
```

```bash
$ yamlfix -c myconfig.toml test.yml
[+] YamlFix: Fixing files
[+] Fixed test.yml
[+] Checked 1 files: 1 fixed, 0 left unchanged
```

```bash
$ cat test.yml
test: some test data
```

This is described [in the documentation](https://lyz-code.github.io/yamlfix/#provide-config-files).

You may also use an environment variable to trigger the same behaviour without needing a separate configuration file.  This may be what you may want to do if removing the YAML document start marker is the only setting you want to change from the default:

```bash
$ cat test.yml
---
test: some test data
```

```bash
$ YAMLFIX_EXPLICIT_START=false yamlfix test.yml
[+] YamlFix: Fixing files
[+] Fixed test.yml
[+] Checked 1 files: 1 fixed, 0 left unchanged
```

```bash
$ cat test.yml
test: some test data
```